# how can i listen a checked event knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have a input form with checkboxes
and i want to call a method when the checkbox is checked, and to get a value of the checkbox in the method
how can i do this by using checked binding knockout js?
i know how can i use the checked binding

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : myCheckbox">
<span data-bind="text : myCheckbox"></span>
js//
var ViewModel = {
  myCheckbox : ko.observable(true) ;
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel)
```

but i don't know how can i call the method when the checkbox is checked without click binding

Answer (score 2):

You want to [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the bound variable. In your example here, the value is just going to be true or false.

```js
var vm = {
  myCheckbox: ko.observable(true)
}

vm.myCheckbox.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.debug(newValue);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : myCheckbox">
<span data-bind="text : myCheckbox"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could attach another binding - `click`?  Would something like this work for you?

```
var ViewModel = {
  myCheckbox : ko.observable(true),
  handle: function(value){
    console.log(value.myCheckbox());
    return true;
  }
}

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : myCheckbox, click: handle">
<span data-bind="text : myCheckbox"></span>
```

Comment: i'd like to call a method every time when some of my checkboxes are checked, a click just change the value of the checkboxes and my method must be called depending on the value of the checkboxes, true or false

Comment: I think the click bind isn't the right way to do that